# External storage to internal storage

Tags: java, android

I am making a program that would save the inputted word in an EditText to a textfile in sd card. However, there is something wrong about mounting sd card in my tablet so im thinking of saving the text file to internal storage instead. Can anyone please help me how to switch this to internal storage? any comment would be greatly appreciated.thank you.

**Here's my code:**

```
public void writeToSDFile() {


    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
    tv.append("\nExternal file system root: "+root);    

    File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath());
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "wordlist.txt");

    try {   


        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);           

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
        pw.println(stringword);
        pw.append(stringword);        

        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        f.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG, "******* File not found.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    tv.append("\n\nFile written to "+file);    


}//end writeToSDFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since external storage is removable, you should not presume that it exists all the time. Hence before doing any io operation, check the storage state.

About your question to internal storage, There are two ways:
1. In application storage (app cache) - refer: Environment.getDataDirectory()
2. In common Data directory - refer: Context.getCacheDir().

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, so i'll just change getExternalStorageDirectory() to getDataDirectory()?

Comment: I believe so, if you want to store content in Internal Memory. Just to add, for Phones without SDCARD support Phone Storage is also mounted as SDCARD, but since it is not removable, you dont need to worry about the mount state.

Answer (score 2):

This should be able to help you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html